# Hiding Tails on USB drive

Tags: security, tails

How can I hide the Tails software on my USB stick ? I have no idea to do so. I use it, but I'm no developper.

Comment: This isn't something Tails supports. How to "hide" an operating system on a USB device is probably a question bested asked on the Information Security StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

If your USB stick is smart enough - yes. Make it a multipartitional one. If you are good with a soldering iron - make it yourself like [this](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/default.aspx?tab=documents&Asset_Type=020%20Application%20Note) and you should add a button(with a pull resistor of course!) to expose or not the "hidden" partition. This button is better be well-concealed, or even implemented as a magnetic stealth switch inside the pendrive case.